# Wordpress site blank after logging in

Tags: php, wordpress

This is regarding the website http://brijux.com

The website is working as expected now, except when I login to the admin area.

When I login, I only see a blank white page with nothing in it. The website works find without logging in as admin.

More info:
- I haven't updated wordpress

- I haven't changed themes or upgraded themes since it was working last time
- I haven't added any plugin or upgraded plugins since it was working last time
- I had wordpress super cache plugin enabled. Might that be the reason that the site is working when I am not logged in and serving cached pages?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error messages you posted in earlier comments, it looks like your memory limit is too low.  You have it set to 32M, so try the following line in your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

That will double your memory limit to 64 megabytes (keep raising it if that's not enough).  See here for more info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP

Comment: I tried to increase WP_MEMORY_LIMIT to 64M in wp-config.php and wp-settings.php but I am having the same error.

Looking at the phpinfo, it seems that my host is limiting it to 32M

Do you know what could be the reason that the site worked fine for around 3 years with 32M and now I am seeing this error suddenly?

Answer (score 0):

Blank pages on a PHP site usually mean a fatal error and error_reporting is turned off. Check the PHP and/or server log (error_log in particular) for details as to what's blowing up.

Comment: I am not sure if you get notified if I reply to someone else's comment.

So posting the above comment here as well to get more eyes on it.

Thanks. It is giving me bunch of debug messages now. There are multiple `Notice:` and one 

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /xxx/wp-admin/menu.php on line 235`

Answer (score 0):

There's a PHP error in your codebase. Set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in your wp_config.php file.

Comment: There is no `WP_DEBUG` in wp_config.php

Comment: Thanks. It is giving me bunch of debug messages now. There are multiple `Notice:` and one 

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 491520 bytes) in /xxx/wp-admin/menu.php on line 235`